# Can I use taxonomies to make a multistore with woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Can I use taxonomies to make a multistore with woocommerce?

I would be needing to have different departments(3), on a same site, with a single WP and woocommerce installation. Avoiding multisite if possible (template conflicts).

Is it possible to make a custom taxonomy("department") and manage my store with custom queries as a multi-departmental one??

Comment: Considered using a multivendor plugin like: https://wedevs.com/dokan/ ?

Comment: Using Woocommerce is mandatory for this project, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Dokan works on top of WooCommerce, it adds extra functionality such as multivendor.

Comment: I will give it a try. I dont need frontend products posting but this plugin looks like a tempting alternative.